# How can I limit disk access bandwidth for a Virtual Machine guest?

Tags: virtualbox, virtualization, disk-usage

I have a Virtualbox on my Ubuntu (host) that serves few Windows guest OS.
Sometimes the running Windows virtual machine starts massive access to the disk which blocks me in my host environment. I would like to limit the read/write of data access to the physical harddisk.

How can I do it?

Comment: Sounds very much like a bug. What sort of activity caused the problem ? Are you running out of RAM (how much swap space are you using ? )

Comment: There might be many reasons for massive access and you are right about one of them. However, my question is a generic one about limiting a VM so that even when it wants to the host won't allow it to use some portion of the bandwidth.

Comment: @bodhi.zazen I want to limit access (reads/writes) to the hard disk. RAM and CPU can be limited from the VM image settings but if an guest is doing heavy reading/writing to the disk (virtual disk of course) then there is no limit on that.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Starting from version 4.0 we are able to limit Virtual Box bandwith for acess to disk images (see [Virtual Box Manual](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch05.html#storage-bandwidth-limit) for details)

We need to create a bandwith group first (in the example below named "Limit" for 20 MB/s):

```
VBoxManage bandwidthctl "VM name" add Limit --type disk --limit 20M
VBoxManage storageattach "VM name" --storagectl "SATA" --port 0 --device 0 --type hdd
                                   --medium disk1.vdi --bandwidthgroup Limit
VBoxManage storageattach "VM name" --storagectl "SATA" --port 1 --device 0 --type hdd
                                   --medium disk2.vdi --bandwidthgroup Limit
```

If you get this error:

```
VBoxManage: error: Cannot register the hard disk '.../foo.vdi' {...} because a hard disk '.../foo.vdi' with UUID {...} already exists
```

then replace the path to the disk image with the UUID given in the error (both should be the same) including the `{}`

To further limit disk access to 10 MB/s we can then issue

```
VBoxManage bandwidthctl "VM name" set Limit --limit 10M
```

This can even be done during runtime.

Comment: --controller is no longer the correct command. It should now be --storagectl "*SATA Controller Name*" To limit access while the VM is running the command is VBOXManage bandwidthctrl "VMName" --name Limit --limit 10

Comment: Nice answer. But the command here in Virtual Box 4.2.12 was `VBoxManage bandwidthctl "VM Name" add "Limit" --type disk --limit 10` and `VBoxManage storageattach "VM Name" --storagectl "SATA" --port 0 --device 0 --type hdd --medium "Disk Name.vdi" --bandwidthgroup "Limit"`.